# Optimizing fortran program using gcc or icc

Tags: optimization, gcc, fortran, icc

I find it terribly hard to find any "formal" documentation about fortran online. I want to know how to optimize the code (compilation wise) I tried the -O3 using f95 compiler but I want to know if there is anything else I can do. As for icc, this is a future issue and I only want to be "prepared".

Comment: Oh, by the way `icc` is the name that Intel use for their C/C++ compiler, you probably meant `ifort`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why it is terribly hard for you to find 'formal' documentation about Fortran online.  I just Googled the search term *optimizing fortran programs* and got about 4.5M hits.  On the first page about 6 (out of 10) would be worth looking at at least briefly; some of the links pointed back here to SO questions and answers.

To help you prepare for using Intel compilers here's a link to their [documentation](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-composer-xe-2011-documentation) .  If you wander around the Intel site you'll find useful information on optimising your programs which is applicable to many compilers, not just the Intel products.

Your first resource for optimisation-by-compiler ought to be the documentation for your compiler, which will show you all the options available.  It ought to tell you, for example, what options `-O3` engages.  On most compilers I've used the `-O` optimisation option is a short hand for a number of other flags, and it's interesting to see the effect of those flags individually or in combinations other than all-or-none.

[The Fortran Company web-site](http://www.fortran.com/) is another useful jumping-off point for your searches.  I could go on, but won't.